# union and intersection operations on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, aws-elasticsearch

I have two different dynamoDB databases, one for in person students:
{teacherID, studentID, year}

and one for online class subscribers:
{teacherID, subscriberID, subscribed_date}

I want to find list of :

(1) In person students of that teacher who are also subscribed online

(2) Either in person students or online subscribers

I am thinking of using aws elasticsearch indexes built on top of these dynamoDB tables. However, I haven't found any ways online to do this. Is there a way to do this in elastic search?

Comment: ES will not be good tool if you plan on keeping the two tables separate. You will need to normalize the documents for you to get optimal performance out of ES. Look at ES help topics for nested documents, queries and aggregation to see if this will suit your needs.

Comment: @sramalingam24 ... **de**normalize ;-)

Comment: Denormalized :)

Comment: Another option would be to use Nested Types: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html